# Tensorflow multi-GPU training and variable scope

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

**Context**

I'm working on a detector model on multiple GPUs using Tensorflow 1.0. As suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py), Gradients are computed on multiple GPUs individually and are averaged on CPU. To share the trainable variables (e.g. weights and biases) across the GPU towers, the `reuse` flag is turned on using `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()`, as in the cifar10 example. The difference is that I am using an `AdamOptimizer` instead of `GradientDescentOptimizer`.

**Problem**

When I run the training job, it prints out a long stacktrace and raise the following error at `opt.apply_gradients()`:

`ValueError: Variable conv1_1/kernel/Adam/ does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?`

**Analysis**

Looking into the source code I found that the `AdamOptimizer` is creating a number of zero-initialized slots within the `_create_slots()` method, wherein it calls the `_zeros_slot()`. This calls a separate module called the [`slot_creator`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/slot_creator.py#L62) (source code linked).

**In `line 62` of the `slot_creator`, it uses `variable_scope.get_variable()`. This used to be `tf.Variable()` in 0.12.**

My understanding of variable scopes is that `variable_scope.get_variable()` would fail to create a variable **if `reuse` flag is on`. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L669) for source code.**

But the cifar10 example by Tensorflow creators seems to suggest enabling reuse to share variables across the GPU towers using `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()`. This happens **before** we average and apply the gradients. It looks like Tensorflow 1.0 refuses to create variables for the `AdamOptimizer`.

This happens for all optimizers that directly or indirectly call the `slot_creator` module.

**Question**

As a quick fix, I added a custom function into the `VariableScope` class to disable the `_reuse` flag right before calling `opt.apply_gradients`. However, I am sure there is a merit to forcing the `reuse` flag to be only set to `True`. I am not sure what the better workaround would be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the cifar10 code, moving `grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)` in front of the `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` line should solve the problem.